# How to update code at runtime in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a simple scenario (Rails 4 using Passenger):

1) One developing machine.
2) Multiple customers of the system being developed on machine 1. The system runs at customer's facilities in a virtual machine that is identical of the developing machine.

In this system, we are trying to make a feature that shows (only for the administrator) a page on which he can click a button (update code) and the system would do:

1. Connect to git server.
2. Run git pull.
3. touch tmp/restart.txt.

We setup all certificates in order not to ask for a password, setup Passenger/Apache to use the same user which is the owner of Rails app and, **in console**, it works using this code:

```
....
item = "git pull"
@result = %x[ #{item} ]
....
```

But, when I run this inside my app, it doesn't do anything and doesn't output nothing yet.
One strange clue is that when I change the command for some command that doesn't have to access git server (for instance, git status), it works flawlessly (remember that, in console, at the same virtual machine, the code works)

If anyone could help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to assume to much, but it sounds like you need to implement a Continuous Integration (CI) strategy.  I assume that the Admin is going to push this "button" when they are informed that there is new code, correct?

Have you guys attempted to use something like [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) to push updates to the customer system?

EDIT:

Suggest using popen -

```
# Get new code
IO.popen "cd #{Rails.root} && git pull" do |io|
    io.each { |line| Rails.logger.info line }
end

# Bundle if necessary
IO.popen "cd #{Rails.root} && bundle" do |io|
    io.each { |line| Rails.logger.info line }
end

# Migrate if necessary
IO.popen "cd #{Rails.root} && rake db:migrate" do |io|
    io.each { |line| Rails.logger.info line }
end

# Restart Passenger
IO.popen "cd #{Rails.root} && touch tmp/restart.txt" do |io|
    io.each { |line| Rails.logger.info line }
end
```

You might also want to shove this in a shell script and call that.

Comment: Yes, they push the button whenever they want and, when we push something at github, the procedure would pull and update their system.
We've studied Capistrano but all scenarios assumes that **we** would start the update procedure and we know where clients are but we don't.
They have our system installed in their environment and it's their call to update their system whenever they want.

Comment: So what happens if you add a new migration or gem?

Comment: see update, I bet you are not changing the directory prior to running the commands.

Comment: I thought about that too and ran a command like 'pwd' which gave me '/usr/app' (the app directory) and thought about my user and, after some research, changed in Apache configuration adding a line 'PassengerUser <user of app>'. Any other thoughts?
Regarding gems or migrations, this won't happen at this stage of the project. In the future, we will work on this scenario.

Comment: it keeps doing nothing and logging nothing (but it runs the commands). What it's more strange is when I run the same command in console, it runs fine.

Comment: Using webrick in production mode, it works fine. It seems that it's something related with Apache/Passenger

Comment: I chose your solution as you've bothered answering it and your solution is better than the code I had but actually the problem I faced was that when there is no console, ssh-agent is not there to input password and github didn't authenticate at all. If I use a password-less certificate, it works fine.